# Ingress with single service on docker on mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Completely new do K8s here, I'm trying to deploy/connect Ingress to a sample single service on `docker for local` (docker for mac) and be able to hit it to run the service

1- sample service looks like this (`my_service.js`) :

```
const express = require('express')
let app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello service')
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000
app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log('Listening')
    )
```

and I build the image (with a docker file):

```
docker build . -t sample-service-image
```

2- Now from K8s perspective:
here's the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-service
  labels:
    app: sample-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-service
        image: sample-service-image
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
```

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

and expose it as a service:

```
kubectl expose deploy sample-service --type=NodePort
```

3- Now from Ingress (ingress-sample.yaml) :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-sample
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: sample-service
    servicePort: 80
```

```
kubectl create -f ingress-sample.yaml
```

[UPDATE] I deployed an ingress controller from [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
```

this is what I get

```
$kubectl get ingress
NAME             HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-sample   *       localhost   80      8m
```

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces | grep nginx
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx    NodePort    10.106.47.48     <none>        80:31448/TCP,443:31512/TCP   2h
```

tried to hit it on `http://localhost:31448/` but I get `503` from NGINX ... so I guess it's not properly connected to `sample-service`.

how should I hit Ingress to be able to call the sample-service?

Comment: Do you have an Ingress Controller installed ? An Ingress will not work until there is an Ingress Controller.

Comment: Consider installing Nginx Ingress Controller: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal

Comment: yea thanks, I didn't have the Ingress controller, launched it as Vasily mentioned. 
now I see ```$kubectl get ingress
NAME             HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-sample   *       localhost   80      1m```

now how should I hit Ingress ? `http://localhost/` gives me `503` from NGINX ... so looks like it's running but probably not connecting to the sample service

Comment: even i am facing same issue, with minikube it's working , if anyone has any solution please share it

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `Host` header while hitting your service. For example

```
curl -H "HOST: abc" http://localhost:31448/
```

Since your ingress definition did not specify any host configuration, you can pass any value.

For more information - [see](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1803#issuecomment-459195838).